# PHP cURL is not loaded on modifying php.ini

Tags: php, curl

To enable cURL in PHP I uncomment this line

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

But cURL did not load on restarting Apache. Even on restarting the machine. I have PHP 5.2.1 installed with AppServer on windows XP.

Please help me enabling cURL. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have php_curl.dll in your PHP/ext directory?

Comment: Yes I have the php_curl.dll in my PHP/ext folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out:

1. Download the copy of the [win32 PHP](http://php.net/downloads.php) (not the installer one) from php.net (whichever php version that you want running on your webserver).
2. Then from the `dll` folder, copy these two files: `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` to your `Windows/System32` (whichever Windows you have).
3. And then from the extensions folder: get your `php_curl.dll` and place it under your `/php/extensions` folder.
4. Check your `php.ini` to ensure it's referring to the correct extension folder, for example:

   ```
   extension_dir = "./extensions/"
   ```

   And uncomment your extension to `php_curl.dll` for example:

   ```
   extension=php_curl.dll
   ```
5. Restart Apache

Thanks. Hope it works for you.

Comment: +1 Saved me an eternity of debugging. For me that didn't work right of the bat but i noticed i had the same files in the apache bin dir so i just removed them from there, restarted my server and there we go :)

Comment: Now with PHP 7 I can't get curl to load and unfortunately these instructions didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

I upgraded to PHP 5.6.4 and curl stopped working. php.ini and ext were fine.

I solved this problem by adding C:\php (my php folder) to system variable Path in the Control Panel->System-Advanced->Environment Variables.

Comment: But this is probably linked with the libeay32 path problem.  They are in /php/ folder so the Environment Variable solve the issue.  So you have the choice of moving the files or make the path "global".

Answer (score 0):

For others who didn't get php 7.1 to load with any of these answers, see [Enable cURL on PHP7 windows10 64 bit Apache 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820953/enable-curl-on-php7-windows10-64-bit-apache-2-4#answer-42889258)