# php curl not working in localhost

Tags: php, curl

Manually installed php. But curl not working.
Settings

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
    extension=php_curl.dll
    extension=php_fileinfo.dll
    extension=php_gd2.dll
   ;extension=php_gettext.dll
```

my code:

```
if  (in_array  ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {

        echo "CURL is available on your web server";

    }  else {
        echo "CURL is not available on your web server";
    }
?>
```

Ans:
CURL is not available on your web server

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Manually installed means what you uncommented this like `extension=php_curl.dll`?

Comment: Where's the code? What's the error? Just posting the extensions gives us very little to go on.

Comment: Yes uncommented but not showing in phpinfo.php

Comment: if  (in_array  ('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {

        echo "CURL is available on your web server";

    }  else {
        echo "CURL is not available on your web server";
    }
?>

Comment: CURL is not available on your web server

Comment: check if "php_curl.dll" is avialable in your ext folder .

Comment: yes available. version VC11 x64 Thread Safe

Comment: @JishinAV What are you using WAMP or XAMPP or Linux OS..?

Comment: Windows. manual install that means first install apache, then php

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps from obtaining PHP to enabling cURL:

Download PHP (these steps tested with 7.1)
Add PHP folder to PATH environment variable
Update php.ini file with absolute path for extension directory and uncomment php_curl.dll and php_openssl.dll extensions
Update httpd.conf (Apache config file) to load php7apache2_4.dll module in PHP folder and set PHPIniDir to PHP directory
Copy libeay32.dll libssh2.dll and ssleay32.dll into apache/bin (replace existing)
Restart Apache.

[Enable cURL on PHP7 windows10 64 bit Apache 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820953/enable-curl-on-php7-windows10-64-bit-apache-2-4)